# nth symmetric power of a Riemann surface and its Jacobian

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hilbert-schemes, riemann-surfaces

Let $C$ be a Riemann surface of genus $g$, $Sym^{n}C$ be the nth symmetric power of $C$ with $n\geq 2g$, and $JC$ denote the Jacobian of $C$.

Question: Is it generally true that $Sym^{n}C\cong JC\times\mathbb{P}^{n-g}$, where $\mathbb{P}^{n-g}$ is a projective bundle?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Not quite. It won't be a product.
What is true is that via the Abel-Jacobi map
$Sym^n C\to JC$ is a $\mathbb{P}^{n-g}$ bundle for large $n$.


Comment: Let $P(z)$ and $q(z)$ be the poincare polynomial of $Sym^{n}C$ and $\mathbb{P}^{n-g}$ respectively。

Is it true that the poincare polynomial of $JC$ is the product of $P(z)$ and $q(z)$？

Could you please give me some reference to how $JC$ and $Sym^{n}C$ are related?

Thanks a lot

Comment: @TL: Yes, it is true as the fibration $Sym^nC\to JC$ has structure group $GL$ (i.e., is associated to a vector bundle).

Comment: The book of Arbarello-Cornalba-Griffiths-Harris on algebraic curves has a lot of detail on the geometry of symmetric products, such as the Chern classes of the vector bundle over $JC$ whose projectivization is the (large) $n$th symmetric product.

Comment: See McDonald, Topology 1, 1962. He computes the cohomology ring of $Sym^n C$ (additively isomorphic to that of the product by the Leray-Hisch theorem) and his computations show that there is no retraction Sym^n C \to P^{n-g}$. In the stable case, $Sym^{\infty} C$ is a product by Dold-Thom.

Comment: Thank you so much Donu, Torsten, Tim and Johannes!

These are really helpful!

Comment: @TL Apr 28 at 16:06 --- I think that is incorrect; rather, the Poincare polynomial of $\operatorname{Sym}^n C$ is equal to the product of the Poincare polynomial of $\mathbb{P}^{n-g}$ and that of $J$.

Comment: @Johannes: It is MacDonald, "Symmetric products of an algebraic curve".